# Linear extension with restrictions

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

A problem has come up in which I have a partial order $\leq$ and I need to extend it to a linear order $\leq^{*}$ obeying a series of restrictions that, for given elements $a,b,c$, $a \leq^{*} b \leq^{*} c$ is forbidden. $a \leq^{*} b$, $a \leq^{*} c$ and $b \leq^{*} c$ are all allowed: the restriction only forbids that $b$ is placed in between $a$ and $c$. In summary, if $a \leq^{*} c$, then either $b \leq^{*} a$ or $c \leq^{*} b$.

Does this type of linear extension have a name?

Comment: How is $a \le b \le c$ forbidden when $a \le b$, $a \le c$ and $b \le c$ are allowed?  Isn't $a \le b \le c$ just a compact way of saying $a \le b$ and $b \le c$ (and $a \le c$ which is implied by transitivity of partial/linear orders)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write that $a \leq^{*} b \leq^{*} c$ (not $a \leq b \leq c$) is forbidden (I edited the question with this correction).  $(a,b)$, $(a,c)$ and $(b,c)$ are not (in general) ordered pairs of $\leq$, but they are allowed in $\leq^{*}$ under the condition that $a \leq^{*} b \leq^{*} c$ is not true. In summary, if $a \leq^{*} c$, then either $b \leq^{*} a$ or $c \leq^{*} b$.

Comment: This is kind of like a discrete set, if you are saying the open set $(a, c) =\{a, c\}$